# Maximum sum of non consecutive elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of positive integers, what's the most efficient algorithm to find non-consecutive elements from this array which, when added together, produce the maximum sum?

Comment: Just trying to clarify. I think that for {1,2,3,8,9} the sum is 1+3+9 ...

Comment: I think the statement of the problem is unambiguous if read carefully. @belaisarius, {1, 3, 9} would be the right answer for {1, 2, 3, 8, 9}. But don't assume from this that merely picking the alternate elements is going to work.

Comment: @Frederick yes, perhaps a bad example. I was just trying to show up that the non-consecutive part was being lost in the answers and comments

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Dynamic programming? Given an array `A[0..n]`, let `M(i)` be the optimal solution using the elements with indices `0..i`. Then `M(-1) = 0` (used in the recurrence), `M(0) = A[0]`, and `M(i) = max(M(i - 1), M(i - 2) + A[i]) for i = 1, ..., n`. `M(n)` is the solution we want. This is O(n). You can use another array to store which choice is made for each subproblem, and so recover the actual elements chosen.

Comment: I also want to store the indices of elements that produce the maximum sum, how can I do that?

Answer (score 25):

Let `A` be the given array and `Sum` be another array such that `Sum[i]` represents the maximum sum of non-consecutive elements from `arr[0]..arr[i]`.

We have:

```
Sum[0] = arr[0]
Sum[1] = max(Sum[0],arr[1])
Sum[2] = max(Sum[0]+arr[2],Sum[1])
...
Sum[i] = max(Sum[i-2]+arr[i],Sum[i-1]) when i>=2
```

If `size` is the number of elements in `arr` then `sum[size-1]` will be the answer.

One can code a simple recursive method in top down order as:

```
int sum(int *arr,int i) {
        if(i==0) {
                return arr[0];
        }else if(i==1) {
                return max(arr[0],arr[1]);
        }
        return max(sum(arr,i-2)+arr[i],sum(arr,i-1));
}
```

The above code is very inefficient as it makes exhaustive duplicate recursive calls. To avoid this we use memoization by using an auxiliary array called `sum` as:

```
int sum(int *arr,int size) {
        int *sum = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
        int i;

        for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
                if(i==0) {
                        sum[0] = arr[0];
                }else if(i==1) {
                        sum[1] = max(sum[0],arr[1]);
                }else{
                        sum[i] = max(sum[i-2]+arr[i],sum[i-1]);
                }
        }    
        return sum[size-1];
}
```

Which is `O(N)` in both space and time.

Comment: O(N) extra space can be avoided, instead we need to use only 2 xtra variables which keeps track sum[i - 1] and sum[i - 2] at the end of each iteration.

Comment: This solution is giving me `6` for `1 2 3 4` when my test case says it's supposed to be `10`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 `6` is the correct answer, `10` is the sum of *all* elements, so can't possibly be the correct answer under the constraint of non-consecutiveness.

Comment: @RobinNabel Right, I didn't notice *non* consecutive.

Answer (score 15):

O(N) in time and O(1) in space (DP) solution:

```C
int dp[2] = {a[0], a[1]};
for(int i = 2; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    int temp = dp[1];
    dp[1] = dp[0] + a[i];
    dp[0] = max(dp[0], temp);
}    
int answer = max(dp[0], dp[1]);
```

Comment: Would be great if you could add some comments about what each line does. It's a very optimal and clean solution but for some it's a little too elegant to understand without additional notes.

Comment: How to find the indices?

Comment: This solution is giving me `6` for `1 2 3 4` when my test case says it's supposed to be `10`.

Comment: The question is not clear. The above solution is to find maximum subarray where NO two elements are consecutive.
The above solution is not for the subarray case with consecutive and non consecutive elements both.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That will be in the case of contiguous elements. The given solution is for non-contiguous elements sum.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Given an array of positive numbers, find the maximum sum of elements such
 * that no two adjacent elements are picked
 * Top down dynamic programming approach without memorisation.
 * An alternate to the bottom up approach.
 */

public class MaxSumNonConsec {

public static int maxSum(int a[], int start, int end) {
    int maxSum = 0;

    // Trivial cases
    if (start == end) {
        return a[start];
    } else if (start > end) {
        return 0;
    } else if (end - start == 1) {
        return a[start] > a[end] ? a[start] : a[end];
    } else if (start < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (end >= a.length) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Subproblem solutions, DP
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        int possibleMaxSub1 = maxSum(a, i + 2, end);
        int possibleMaxSub2 = maxSum(a, start, i - 2);

        int possibleMax = possibleMaxSub1 + possibleMaxSub2 + a[i];
        if (possibleMax > maxSum) {
            maxSum = possibleMax;
        }
    }

    return maxSum;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a[] = { 8, 6, 11, 10, 11, 10 };
    System.out.println(maxSum(a, 0, a.length - 1));
}
}
```

Comment: Just to add, the above is a simple recursive implementation, *without* memorization. It's running time can be improved by caching/memorizing solutions to repeating subproblems, say by adding computed sub problems to a hash table and then checking in the hash table before computing a new sub problem.

Answer (score 2):

The solution by @Ismail Badawi does not seem to work in the following case: Let us take the array: `8, 3, 1, 7` Then in this case, the algo returns `max sum = 9` whereas it should be `15`.

A solution to correct it is given an array `A[0..n]`, let `M(i)` be the optimal solution using the elements with indices `0..i`. Then `M(0) = A[0]`, and `M(i) = max(M(i - 1), M(i - 2) + A[i], M(i-3) + A[i]) for i = 3, ..., n`. `M(n)` is the solution we want. This is O(n).

Comment: Ismail's algorithm gives the correct answer for your test case. m[0]=m[1]=8, m[2]= 9, m[3]= max(m[2],m[1] + 7) = 15

Answer (score 1):

IIUC: say your array is 1,2,3,4,5 then 3+5 would be 'correct' and 4+5 not, this means you'll have to find the largest numbers and check if they are consecutive. So an algorithm would be to make use of a second array, for the number of elements you need to add which you fill by traversing the original array and finding the largest non-consecutive integers, then add this up.

For the above array I guess [1,3], [1,4], [1,5], [1,3,5], [2,4], [2,5], [3,5] would be valid non-consecutive integers to be summed, the max sum would be 9 in this case [1,3,5]. So, to adapt the above algorithm, I would suggest you step through the array using several temporary arrays to find all the non-consecutive integer lists, and then check which is the largest. Keep in mind that 'most elements' does not mean 'largest sum'.

Comment: @Jason Williams: Yes, I think I 'got' the problem now ;)

Comment: Find all the sets of non-consecutive elements, then finding the sum of each and then choose the set with the maximum sum would be the correct algorithm. But would it be the most efficient? My suspicion is we can find something better (perhaps linear time), but I'm not sure what that algo could be.

Answer (score 1):

> Dynamic programming solution is the most elegant of all. 
>   And it serves for any value of the distance between two numbers that should not be considered. 
>   But for k= 1, which is for consecutive numbers constraint, I tried using backtracking.
>
> There are different patterns to be compared for the maximum sum.  Below is the list :

```
Number of patterns for 1 = 1    
[1]
Number of patterns for 2 = 2    
[1][2]
Number of patterns for 3 = 2
[1, 3][2]
Number of patterns for 4 = 3
[1, 3][1, 4][2, 4]
Number of patterns for 5 = 4
[1, 3, 5][1, 4][2, 4][2, 5]
Number of patterns for 6 = 5
[1, 3, 5][1, 3, 6][1, 4, 6][2, 4, 6][2, 5]
Number of patterns for 7 = 7
[1, 3, 5, 7][1, 3, 6][1, 4, 6][1, 4, 7][2, 4, 6][2, 4, 7][2, 5, 7]
Number of patterns for 8 = 9
[1, 3, 5, 7][1, 3, 5, 8][1, 3, 6, 8][1, 4, 6, 8][1, 4, 7][2, 4, 6, 8][2, 4, 7][2, 5, 7][2, 5, 8]
Number of patterns for 9 = 12
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9][1, 3, 5, 8][1, 3, 6, 8][1, 3, 6, 9][1, 4, 6, 8][1, 4, 6, 9][1, 4, 7, 9][2, 4, 6, 8][2, 4, 6, 9][2, 4, 7, 9][2, 5, 7, 9][2, 5, 8]
```

> Following is the code in java:

```
public class MaxSeqRecursive {

    private static int num = 5;
    private static int[] inputArry = new int[] { 1,3,9,20,7 };
    private static Object[] outArry;
    private static int maxSum = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        output.add(1);
        convert(output, -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < outArry.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(outArry[i] + ":");
        }

        System.out.print(maxSum);
    }

    public static void convert( List<Integer> posArry, int prevValue) {

        int currentValue = -1;

        if (posArry.size() == 0) {
            if (prevValue == 2) {
                return;
            } else {
                posArry.add(2);
                prevValue = -1;
            }

        }

        currentValue = (int) posArry.get(posArry.size() - 1);

        if (currentValue == num || currentValue == num - 1) {
            updateMax(posArry);
            prevValue = (int) posArry.get(posArry.size() - 1);
            posArry.remove(posArry.size() - 1);
        } else {
            int returnIndx = getNext(posArry, prevValue);
            if (returnIndx == -2)
                return;

            if (returnIndx == -1) {
                prevValue = (int) posArry.get(posArry.size() - 1);
                posArry.remove(posArry.size() - 1);
            } else {
                posArry.add(returnIndx);
                prevValue = -1;
            }
        }
        convert(posArry, prevValue);
    }

    public static int getNext( List<Integer> posArry, int prevValue) {
        int currIndx = posArry.size();
        int returnVal = -1;
        int value = (int) posArry.get(currIndx - 1);

        if (prevValue < num) {
            if (prevValue == -1)
                returnVal = value + 2;
            else if (prevValue - value < 3)
                returnVal = prevValue + 1;
            else
                returnVal = -1;
        }

        if (returnVal > num)
            returnVal = -1;

        return returnVal;
    }

    public static void updateMax(List posArry) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < posArry.size(); i++) {
            sum = sum + inputArry[(Integer) posArry.get(i) - 1];
        }
        if (sum > maxSum) {
            maxSum = sum;
            outArry = posArry.toArray();
        }
    }
}

Time complexity: O( number of patterns to be compared)
```

Comment: Looks like this algorithm is not polynomial but exponential. Patterns are increasing exponentially with the number of elements ( 0,1,2,2,3,4,5,7,9,12,16,21,28,37,49,65,86,114,151,200,265,351,465,616 ). :-(

Comment: Interestingly this pattern is similar to fibonacci series with a minor change ::: 
F(n) = F(n-2) + F(n-3) !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Another Java Implementation ( runs in linear time )

```
public class MaxSum {

private static int ofNonConsecutiveElements (int... elements) {
    int maxsofar,maxi2,maxi1;

    maxi1 = maxsofar = elements[0];
    maxi2 = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
        maxsofar =  Math.max(maxi2 + elements[i], maxi1);
        maxi2 =  maxi1;
        maxi1 = maxsofar;
    }
    return maxsofar;        
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ofNonConsecutiveElements(6, 4, 2, 8, 1));
}
}
```

Comment: { 1,2,13,4,5,9}; try with this input it'll return 23 instead of 22

Answer (score 1):

My solution is O(N) time and O(1) space.

```
private int largestSumNonConsecutive(int[] a) {
    return largestSumNonConsecutive(a, a.length-1)[1];
}
private int[] largestSumNonConsecutive(int[] a, int end) {  //returns array largest(end-1),largest(end)
    if (end==0) return new int[]{0,a[0]};

    int[] largest = largestSumNonConsecutive(a, end-1);
    int tmp = largest[1];
    largest[1] = Math.max(largest[0] + a[end], largest[1]);
    largest[0] = tmp;

    return largest;
}
```

Comment: This is actually O(n) space, since the recursive calls to `largestSumNonConsecutive()` take up space on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
int nonContigousSum(vector<int> a, int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return std::max(nonContigousSum(a, n - 1), nonContigousSum(a, n - 2) + a[n]);
}
```

this is the recursive approach with the help of which we can solve this question
(OPTIMAL SUB-STRUCTURE HALLMARK OF DYNAMIC PROGRAMMING.
Here we are considering two cases, in first we exclude a[n] and in the second we include a[n] and return the max of those sub cases found.
We are basically finding all the subsets of the array and returning the length of the non-contiguous array with max sum.
Use [tabulation or memoization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tabulation-vs-memoizatation/) for avoiding same sub-problems.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. And then: please study the [help] to learn how to properly format your input. It simply doesn't make sense to put up "run code snippet" for C++ code, does it?!

Comment: isn't (n-2) instead of (n-1)? are you assuming array starting at index 1?

Comment: @TechJunkie, thank you I didn't read the part **non-consecutive** elements.

Answer (score 1):

A penny from me.

```
public class Problem {

  /**
   * Solving by recursion, top down approach. Always try this recursion approach and then go with
   * iteration. We have to add dp table to optimize the time complexity.
   */
  public static int maxSumRecur(int arr[], int i) {
    if(i < 0) return 0;
    if(i == 0) return arr[0];
    if(i == 1) return Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);

    int includeIthElement = arr[i] + maxSumRecur(arr, i-2);
    int excludeIthElement = maxSumRecur(arr, i-1);
    return Math.max(includeIthElement, excludeIthElement);
  }

  /**
   * Solving by iteration. Bottom up approach.
   */
  public static void maxSumIter(int arr[]) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    int dp[] = new int[arr.length];
    dp[0] = arr[0];
    dp[1] = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);

    for(int i=2; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
      dp[i] = Math.max(arr[i] + dp[i-2], dp[i-1]);
    }

    System.out.println("Max subsequence sum by Iteration " + dp[arr.length - 1] + "\n");
  }

  public static void maxSumRecurUtil(int arr[]) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    System.out.println("Max subsequence sum by Recursion " + maxSumRecur(arr, arr.length - 1) +
        "\n");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    maxSumRecurUtil(new int[]{5, 5, 10, 100, 10, 5});
    maxSumRecurUtil(new int[]{20, 1, 2, 3});

    maxSumIter(new int[]{5, 5, 10, 100, 10, 5});
    maxSumIter(new int[]{20, 1, 2, 3});

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of numbers that is the odd or even sums corresponding to each number so far; e.g. for input of `[1,2,4,1,2,3,5,3,1,2,3,4,5,2]` the odd-even sums would be `[1,2,5,3,7,6,12,9,13,11,16,15,21,17]`

Now walk the list backwards greedily summing but skipping those elements whose odd/even sum is less than that of next-to-be-considered element.

```
src = [1,2,4,1,2,3,5,3,1,2,3,4,5,2]

odd_even_sums = src[:2]
for i in xrange(2,len(src)):
    odd_even_sums.append(src[i] + odd_even_sums[i-2])

best = []
for i in xrange(len(src)-1,-1,-1):
    if i == 0:
        best.append(i)
    elif odd_even_sums[i-1] > odd_even_sums[i]:
        pass
    elif odd_even_sums[i-1] == odd_even_sums[i]:
        raise Exception("an exercise for the reader")
    else:
        best.append(i)

best.reverse()

print "Best:",",".join("%s=%s"%(b,src[b]) for b in best)
print "Scores:",sum(odd_even_sums[b] for b in best)
```

Outputs:

```
Best: 0=1,1=2,2=4,4=2,6=5,8=1,10=3,12=5
Scores: 77
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int findMaxSum(int[] a){
        int sum0=0; //will hold the sum till i-2        
        int sum1=0;//will hold the sum till i-1
        for(int k : a){
            int x=Math.max(sum0+k, sum1);//max(sum till (i-2)+a[i], sum till (i-1))
            sum0=sum1;
            sum1=x;
        }
        return sum1;
    }
```

**Below is the crux of algorithm:**

**`max(max sum till (i-2)+a[i], max sum till (i-1))`**

**O(N) time complexity  and O(1) space complexity.**

Comment: In this, we r taking the max between the sum of the ith element of array plus the i-2th element of dp array and the i-1th element of the dp array. But it could be the case that the i-1th element was not used to make the sum at dp[i-1]. If that is the case, we could technically add the ith element to this too right? Can someone explain why this isn't necessary?

Answer (score 0):

A rather naive yet complete implementation. 
Recursion equation is T(n) = n^2 + nT(n-3), which if I'm not wrong leads to exponential time. The (n-3) comes from the fact a number cannot add with itself/previous/next numbers.

The program reports the constituent list that makes up the sum (there are multiple, exponentially growing, of these lists, but it just picks one).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class MaxSumNoAdjacent {

    private static class Sum {
        int sum;
        List<Integer> constituents = new ArrayList<>();

        Sum(int sum, List<Integer> constituents) {
            this.sum = sum;
            this.constituents = constituents;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "sum: " + sum + " " + constituents.toString(); 
        }
    }

    public static Sum maxSum(int[] arr) {
        List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i : arr) {
            if (i != Integer.MIN_VALUE) { //Integer.MIN_VALUE indicates unreachability
                input.add(i);
            }
        }

        if (input.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        if (input.size() == 1) {
            List<Integer> constituents = new ArrayList<>();
            constituents.add(input.get(0));
            return new Sum(input.get(0), constituents);
        }

        if (input.size() == 2) {
            int max = Math.max(input.get(0), input.get(1));
            List<Integer> constituents = new ArrayList<>();
            constituents.add(max);
            return new Sum(max, constituents);
        }

        Map<Integer, int[]> numberAndItsReachability = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            int[] neighbours = new int[input.size()];
            if (i > 0) {
                neighbours[i-1] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; //unreachable to previous
            }

            if (i < input.size()-1) {
                neighbours[i+1] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; //unreachable to next
            }

            neighbours[i] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; //unreachable to itself

            for (int j = 0; j < neighbours.length; j++) {
                if (neighbours[j] == 0) {
                    neighbours[j] = input.get(j); //remember values of reachable neighbours
                }
            }

            numberAndItsReachability.put(input.get(i), neighbours);
        }

        Sum maxSum = new Sum(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null);
        for (Entry<Integer, int[]> pair : numberAndItsReachability.entrySet()) {
            Sum sumMinusThisNumber = maxSum(pair.getValue()); //call recursively on its reachable neighbours
            if (sumMinusThisNumber != null) {
                int candidateSum = sumMinusThisNumber.sum + pair.getKey();
                if (maxSum.sum < candidateSum) {
                    sumMinusThisNumber.constituents.add(pair.getKey());
                    maxSum = new Sum(candidateSum, sumMinusThisNumber.constituents);
                }
            }

        }

        return maxSum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = {3,2,5,10,7};
        int[] arr2 = {3,2,7,10};
        int[] arr3 = {5,5,10,40,50,35};
        int[] arr4 = {4,4,4,4};
        System.out.println(maxSum(arr1).toString());
        System.out.println(maxSum(arr2).toString());
        System.out.println(maxSum(arr3).toString());
        System.out.println(maxSum(arr4).toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# version for reference (you may refer to: http://dream-e-r.blogspot.com/2014/07/maximum-sum-of-non-adjacent-subsequence.html):

In-order to solve a problem using dynamic programming there should be a solution which has optimal substructure and overlapping sub problems properties. And the current problem has optimal substructure property. 
Say, f(i) is defined as maximum subsequence sum of non adjacent elements for 'i' items, then

f( i) =     0 if i = 0
            max (f(i-1), f(i-2) + a[i])

Below is the algorithm for the same (no
te it can solved without the encapsulating data in 'record' - i just preferred it this way) - which should illustrate the above idea:

```
int FindMaxNonAdjuscentSubsequentSum(int[] a)
        {
            a.ThrowIfNull("a");
            if(a.Length == 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            Record r = new Record()
            {
                max_including_item = a[0],
                max_excluding_item = 0
            };
            for (int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                var t = new Record();
                //there will be only two cases
                //1. if it includes the current item, max is maximum of non adjuscent sub
                //sequence sum so far, excluding the last item
                t.max_including_item = r.max_excluding_item + a[i];
                //2. if it excludes current item, max is maximum of non adjuscent subsequence sum
                t.max_excluding_item = r.Max;
                r = t;
            }
            return r.Max;
        }
```

**Unit Tests**

```
[TestMethod]
        [TestCategory(Constants.DynamicProgramming)]
        public void MaxNonAdjascentSubsequenceSum()
        {
            int[] a = new int[] { 3, 2, 5, 10, 7};
            Assert.IsTrue(15 == this.FindMaxNonAdjuscentSubsequentSum(a));
            a = new int[] { 3, 2, 5, 10 };
            Assert.IsTrue(13 == this.FindMaxNonAdjuscentSubsequentSum(a));
            a = new int[] { 5, 10, 40, 50, 35 };
            Assert.IsTrue(80 == this.FindMaxNonAdjuscentSubsequentSum(a));
            a = new int[] { 1, -1, 6, -4, 2, 2 };
            Assert.IsTrue(9 == this.FindMaxNonAdjuscentSubsequentSum(a));
            a = new int[] { 1, 6, 10, 14, -5, -1, 2, -1, 3 };
            Assert.IsTrue(25 == this.FindMaxNonAdjuscentSubsequentSum(a));
        }
```

**where**

```
public static int Max(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a > b) ? a : b;
        }
        class Record
        {
            public int max_including_item = int.MinValue;
            public int max_excluding_item = int.MinValue;
            public int Max
            {
                get
                {
                    return Max(max_including_item, max_excluding_item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int maxSumNoAdj(int[] nums){
    int[] dp = new int[nums.length];
    dp[0] = Math.max(0, nums[0]); // for dp[0], select the greater value (0,num[0])
    dp[1] = Math.max(nums[1], Math.max(0, dp[0]));    
    int maxSum = Math.max(dp[0], dp[1]);
    for(int i = 2; i < nums.length; i++){
        int ifSelectCurrent = Math.max(nums[i] + dp[i-2], dp[i-2]);// if select, there are two possible
        int ifNotSelectCurrent = Math.max(dp[i-1], dp[i-2]);        // if not select, there are two posible
        dp[i] = Math.max(ifSelectCurrent, ifNotSelectCurrent);      // choose the greater one
        maxSum = Math.max(dp[i], maxSum);   // update the result
    }
    return maxSum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = {-9, 2, 3, -7, 1, 1};
    System.out.println(maxSumNoAdj(nums));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of question can be solved in `theta(n)` space and time complexity using dynamic programming.

**Approach**

- Make dp array of size `(n + 1)` where n is the length of given array.
- Initialise this dp array with None.
- Equate the second element of this dp array = first element of given array. We have equated the second element of this dp array because indexing start with zero. In short, `dp[1] = arr[0]`.
- Equate the third element of this dp array to max of first and second element of the given array i.e `dp[2] = max(arr[0], arr[1])`.
- Now use below code to fill rest element of the dp array.

  `for i in range(3, n + 1):`
  `dp[i] = max(dp[i - 1], dp[i - 2] + arr[i - 1])`

where `dp[i - 1]` denotes that element is not included.
`(dp[i - 2] + arr[i - 1])` denotes that element is included.

**Code snippet**

[image]