# Maximum sum of non-consecutive elements (with k elements from anywhere)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

An altered version to the question of "Given an array of positive integers, what's the most efficient algorithm to find non-consecutive elements from this array which, when added together, produce the maximum sum?" The standard version is answered quite well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487438/maximum-sum-of-non-consecutive-elements).

But what if you also can pick a specified number of elements from *anywhere* in the list, regardless if they are consecutive or not? How would you find the max sum in this case?

To make clear with an example, say you are building houses. You have n housing lots to choose from. Each lot has a financial value associated with it, X[i] that you will get if you build a house there. But, due to zoning laws, you cannot build on consecutive lots (so if you build on lot #5, you can't build on #4 or #6). You want to build houses in such a way to maximize the value. So if H[ ] is the list of houses you are to build, the problem would be `H[i] = max ((H(i-1), H(i-2) + X[i])).`

But now, what if you have an additional k-zoning permits (where k is given to you) that let you build anywhere, in addition to the fixed lots?

Comment: Pick the largest k. OR did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: K is fixed, that was confusing on my part. Post edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be solved with a simple dynamic programming algorithm:

1. create a list of tuples (e.g. `tuples`); this list contains two objects: the total value of constructed houses, and the list of housing lots chosen (e.g. `lots`)
2. initialize the list to one element, with value 0 and an empty list of lots
3. iterate through all possible housing lots. for every lot `L`:
4. loop through the list: for every tuple `T` in the list:
5. if the house can be added to the list of housing lots (i.e. there are less than k lots in the list, and adding `L` wouldn't break the non-consecutive rule), create another element in the list, sum the value of the `T` with the value of building on this lot (you called this `X[i]`) and add `L` to the list of `lots` in `T`.
6. loop through `tuples`, find the one with the max `value`. the best choice for the housing lots is stored in that `tuple`'s `lots`

not sure about the complexity of this (n^2*k? - can't think right now) but it's not too bad overall.

the nice thing about this is: with some clever coding, you can reuse the algorithm for any set of rules. just make step 5 accept external conditions.

Comment: the straightforward dynamic programming approach (which takes into account, at each steps, the best solutions with 0 < i < k + 1 "permits" used) is O(nk).

Answer (score 2):

`d[i][j]` - dynamic, how much can we take if the first unused house is `i` and we already have used `j` bonuses.

```C
d[0][0] = 0;  
d[i][j] = max(d[i-1][j], d[i-2][j] + x[i], d[i-1][j-1] + x[i]);
```

Comment: there's nothing better than O(nk)?

Comment: @akappa I think there isn't. Cause it's very similar to knapsack problem - we have no idea which ones items should be marked as allowed.

Comment: yes, but the problem without "free houses" is O(n). I think there are some properties upon the cost of various solution that we can exploit to make something more close to O(n).

Answer (score 0):

First choose the k best elements, then solve the "best non-consecutive integers" problem in the instance *without* the previously selected elements.

Comment: I don't think that solution works. For example, say you have a list of `{2, 8, 6, 2, 10, 4}` and k = 1. If you select the largest value, 10, you'd get a list of `{ 2, 8, 6, 2, x, 4}`. The max of the remaining list would be 14 from 8, 2, and 4. The total max would be 24. But if you instead select 8 from the original list, giving `{2, x, 6, 2, 10, 4}`, you could get a max from 2, 6, and 10, which is 18. Plus the first 8 gives 26.

Comment: Right. I was thinking about the fact that every optimal solution to your problem *must* include the k biggest elements (it's easy to see: you obtain a solution by taking a solution which satisfies the "non-adjacent" constraint and adding the biggest elements not included). I think there is some solution which cleverly exploit this fact, maybe an adaptation of the dynamic programming approach.