# Maximum non-segment sum

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming

We have a list / array of numbers (**positives and negatives are all possible**).

A segment is defined as *contiguous subsequence* of the numbers. For example, [1;-2;3;4;5] is the array and a segment of it is [1;-2;3] or [-2;3;4], etc. All numbers in a segment must be contiguous.

A non-segment is defined as *all subsequences of the array, except all segments*. So **contiguous numbers are possible in a non-segment**, but there must be at least two numbers which are not contiguous.

For example, [1;3;4] is a non-segment, [1;-2;3;5] is also a non-segment because 3 and 5 are not contiguous (there is a '4' between them in the original array).

**The question is what is the non-segment having the maximum sum?**

---

Note

1. Numbers can be mix of positives and negatives
2. It is not the problem of http://algorithmsbyme.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/amazon-interview-question-maximum-possible-sum-with-non-consecutive-numbers/ or [Maximum sum of non consecutive elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487438/maximum-sum-of-non-consecutive-elements). In those problems, no numbers can be contiguous and all numbers are positive.

---

This is problem 11 in the book [Pearls of functional algorithm design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pearls-Functional-Algorithm-Design-Richard/dp/0521513383/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1389310869&sr=8-1&keywords=pearls%20of%20functional%20algorithm%20design) and it says there is a **linear** way to solve it.

But I can't understand nor find out a linear way. So I try my luck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution better suited to the functional programming idiom. One can imagine a four-state finite automaton that accepts strings having two non-adjacent 1s.

```
       0         1         0         0,1
      ___       ___       ___        ___
     v  /  1   v  /  0   v  /  1    v  /
---> (q0) ---> (q1) ---> (q2) ---> ((q3))
```

What the Haskell program below does is essentially to scan the numbers one at a time and remember the maximum values that can be made via choices that, when interpreted as 0s and 1s, put the automaton in state `q1` (`segmentEndingHere`), state `q2` (`segmentNotEndingHere`), or state `q3` (`nonSegment`). This technique is a sledgehammer that works on many of these problems about optimization on a sequence.

```
maximumNonSegmentSum :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe a
maximumNonSegmentSum = mnss Nothing Nothing Nothing
  where  
        (^+) :: (Num a) => a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
        (^+) = liftM . (+)

        mnss ::
             (Num a, Ord a) => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a -> [a] -> Maybe a
        mnss segmentEndingHere segmentNotEndingHere nonSegment xs
          = case xs of
                [] -> nonSegment
                x : xs'
                  -> mnss ((x ^+ segmentEndingHere) `max` Just x)
                       (segmentNotEndingHere `max` segmentEndingHere)
                       (((x `max` 0) ^+ nonSegment) `max` (x ^+ segmentNotEndingHere))
                       xs'
```

Comment: I figured out the way from that book just before your answer. thanks. Also i think this functional way is the best thinking and will help imperative way as well. Have you read that book?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities:

- There exists at most 2 non-negative numbers, and, in the case of 2 existing, they're neighbouring.

  In this case we pick the largest pair of non-neighbouring numbers. This can be done in linear time by finding the largest number and the sum of that with the largest non-neighbouring number, and then the sum of both its neighbouring numbers.

  Example:

  ```
  Input: [-5, -10, -6, -2, -1, -2, -10]
  ```

  The largest number is `-1`, so we sum `-1` and the largest non-neighbouring number (`-5`), which gives `-6`. Then we also try `-2` and `-2`, giving `-4`. So the largest non-segment sum is `-4`.
- There exists at least two non-neighbouring non-negative numbers.

  We pick all positive numbers. If the largest number is zero (i.e. there are no positive numbers), pick all the zero's instead.

  If all the picked numbers are consecutive, try to:

  - Exclude the smallest one that's not on one of the ends.
  - Include the largest (i.e. closest to 0) non-positive number that's not neighbouring to the picked numbers (if there exists such a 0, this would be the best option).
  - In turn, try to exclude the numbers from the ends of the sequence, then include the non-positive number next to it (do this only if there exists a number next to it).

  Pick the option here giving the largest sum.

  Clearly all of this can happen in linear time.

  Example:

  ```
  Input: [-5, -1, 5, 7, 9, 11, -1, -10]
  ```

  So first we pick all positive numbers - `5, 7, 9, 11`, but they're consecutive.

  So we try to exclude the smallest non-end number (`7`),
  giving us `sum(5, 9, 11) = 25`.

  Then we try to include the largest non-neighbouring negative number (`-5`),
  giving us `sum(-5, 5, 7, 9, 11) = 27`.

  Then we try to exclude the left edge (`5`) and include the number next to it (`-1`),
  giving us `sum(-1, 7, 9, 11) = 26`.

  Then we try to exclude the right edge (`11`) and include the number next to it (`-1`),
  giving us `sum(-1, 5, 7, 9) = 20`.

  Clearly the maximum sum is `27`.

  Note how we can make any of the conditions the maximum sum by just changing a value, thus all the conditions are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take all of the positive numbers.  If they form a segment, check if you can add in something not adjacent to it.  Also check if you can pick something off in the middle.  Also check if you can pick off an end and put in the number next to it.  It's not too hard to prove that one of these leads to the best non-segment.