# How to get the numbers/indexes used to find the maximum sum of an array elements when no two elements are adjacent

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I had found these below-mentioned articles useful to find the maximum sum of array elements when no two elements are adjacent.
[Maximum sum of non consecutive elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487438/maximum-sum-of-non-consecutive-elements)
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-adjacent/

But I can't get the logic behind, how to get the numbers used to find the max sum. For example:

```
array => {2, 5, 10, 1, 10}
```

The max sum would be 22 by using 2, 10 and 10, now how to find the numbers/indexes used in case of a large array. In this example how to find I have used 2,10,10 or 0,2,4th indexes of the array? Any type of help is very much appreciated.

[Maximum sum of non consecutive elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487438/maximum-sum-of-non-consecutive-elements)
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-adjacent/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the question you share: Define array `M` where `M[i] = max(M(i - 1), M(i - 2) + A[i]) for i = 1, ..., n`.

Also, create array `I` which will contains the chosen index.

Init everything first by chossing first 2 element of M (avoiding the edge case) as:

```
A = 2, 5, 10, 1, 10 // input array

M = [A[0]]; // index 0 of M is only first element
I = []; // init empty index array
if (A[0] > A[1]) { // if first element bigger
    M[1] = A[0]; //choose him for second place also
    I = [true, false]; // set first two indexs as taking the first element in A and not the second
} else { // the second element is bigger
    M[1] = A[1]; // assign him to M
    I = [false, true] //set I for not taking the first element but the second one
}
```

Now loop on all the `A` array as:

```
for i 2 to cnt(A)-1 {
    if (M[i-1] > M[i-2] + A[i]) { // if prefer to take last place
        M[i] = M[i-1]; // set current max at i
        I[i] = false; // we don't take the current places
    } else {
        M[i] = M[i-2] + A[i]; // set current max at i
        I[i] = true; I[i-1] = false, I[i-2] = true; //change older value as decided to take this path
    }
}
```

For you example:

```
A = 2, 5, 10, 1, 10
M = 2, 5, 12, 12, 22
I = T, F, T, F, T
```