# Modified House Robber

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dynamic

I've been working on a slight modification of the house robber problem.

I was able to generate and program the recurrence relation to find the maximum total.

```
def mod_robber(arr):
  arr[1] = max(arr[0], arr[1])
  for i in range(2, len(arr)):
    arr[i] = max(arr[i]+arr[i-2], arr[i-1])
  return arr[-1]
```

However, I'd like to find *which* houses to rob. For instance; if I give it the array [1, 2, 3, 1] it appropriately returns 4, but I'd like it to return [1, 3].

This is a bottom-up approach in which I fill each index of the list with the most-current maximum, then return the last element. So, in this example; [1, 2, 3, 1] becomes [1, 2, 4, 4] after running the loop with 4 being our maximum.

I have a sneaking suspicion I should be traversing that modified list [1, 2, 4, 4] in reverse, and subtracting from the maximum. But I can't quite figure out a way to make that work in all instances.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487438/maximum-sum-of-non-consecutive-elements) post, asking a similar question. But the answers given all compute the maximum sum, not return the appropriate indices.

Thank you so much for your collective wisdom.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: You seem to be asking us to write code for you -- simply to update and store the coordinates of the locations you found.  There are many examples of how to append results to an accumulation list.  As such, you should have a full coding attempt, rather than a snippet and a general description.

Comment: So I should be copy/pasting all the previous attempts I've made? Because that would be a much longer post. And I'm not really asking someone to write the code for me. More like what are other approaches to this? I've tried keeping and appending to a separate list. I've tried traversing the list backwards and subtracting. I've even tried just a brute force, generating all possible valid lists and returning the one with the maximum sum. That's the only one that works, but it's terribly slow.

Comment: Your initial question is already answered in "how to ask".  An open-ended discussion of alternative algorithms is off-topic here, as covered in "on topic".  Please see [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to choose an appropriate Stack Exchange site for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a list extended with the contributing indexes. So initially, the contributing indexes are just one for each value: its own index. For the example input we would start with:

```
[(1, (0,)), (2, (1,)), (3, (2,)), (1, (3,))]
```

Then it is a matter of correctly adding two entries together:

```
def mod_robber(arr):
    arr = [(val, (i,)) for i, val in enumerate(arr)]
    arr[1] = max(arr[0], arr[1])
    for i in range(2, len(arr)):
        arr[i] = max((arr[i-2][0] + arr[i][0], arr[i-2][1] + (i,)), arr[i-1]) 
    return arr[-1]
```

The output for your example is:

```
(4, (0, 2))
```

...meaning that the maximised value is 4, and the contributing indexes are 0 and 2 (zero-based index numbers).

Comment: Ah! This is an approach I had not thought of: Keeping track of indexes! Thank you so much for your input.